# Can I assign keys to the my calculator in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to coding and to JavaScript, and I wanted to code a calculator as a task. Everything worked well until now:
My question is: Can I use keys to use my calculator? So, e.g. if I want type the number 5 into my calculator, I have to press on the button I created with my mouse. How can I assign keys to them?

Comment: Listen keydown event on `document` ..?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `keydown` event. For example, the following code should solve your problem. It listens for when the 5 key goes down and has a comment where you should call whatever function you need to use.

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
    if(e.code == "Digit5"){
       // Add the number 5 to your calculator
    }
});
```